# into HttpRequestMessage OR IHttpClientFactory set or connect proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, proxy, httprequest

I am beginner. Take it easy on me.
I want to set or connect proxy on that piece of code

```
            var requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(GetHttpMethod(method), url);

            if (method != APIMethod.GET)
            {
                var serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                requestMsg.Content = new StringContent(serializedContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }

            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("xxx.xx.xx.xx", 8080);
            requestMsg.Proxy = myproxy; <------ error


            HttpResponseMessage task = await httpClientFactory.CreateClient().SendAsync(requestMsg);
```

please help me set proxy hard code
i read these but i cant understand
[Proxy with HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367219/proxy-with-http-requests) 
[C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy)

Comment: Maybe you can try to set [HttpClient.DefaultProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64931470/how-to-set-default-proxy-with-net-core-3-1-for-http-client-for-any-request).

Comment: yes you can answer to this question

Comment: Hi,@Alireza heidari,I have added the answer as you suggested,if it is helpful,please accept it as an answer,thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [HttpClient.DefaultProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-5.0) to set the global Http proxy.

```
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy("xxx.xx.xx.xx", 8080);
```